# tinymce on textarea generated by php/jquery post

Tags: php, jquery, tinymce

I have tinymce working well FIRST time you click the button, but after that it doesn't init anymore, no errors however.
To get editor again you need to refresh page.

Is it possible to get init editor to the text area every time you open the modal without refreshing page ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('click', '.btn.modal', function() {
    var title = $('.modal-title'),
        content = $('.modal-body'),
        footer = $('.modal-footer');

    $.post('units.php', { addnew: 'unit' }, function(r) {
      title.html(r.title);
      content.html(r.content);
      footer.html(r.btns);
      tinymce.init({ selector: 'textarea' });
      $('#modal').modal('show');
    },'json');
  });

});
```

Comment: Yes, by initialising it on the moment it has been loaded...

Comment: tinymce.init is already inside post response ?

Comment: You are initialising it yes, but you are doing it the general way, which probably conflicts with the first init you used... So my best guess is you need to destroy them all first and then init them again..

Comment: Try adding `$('textarea').tinymce().destroy();$('textarea').tinymce().remove();` before the init

Comment: Actually adding `tinymce.remove();` before `tinymce.init` was enought. so anyway, have to remove and init it again. Thanks for pointing to right direction anyway :)

Comment: No problem, the destroy doesn't even work, my bad.. Mind if I make an answer out of it?

Comment: Nah, go ahead if you like

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using the general initialisating, which probably conflits with the textarea(s) which already have been initialised... .

The best way to solve this is by destroying all the initialised tinymce first using:

```
$('textarea').tinymce().re‌​move();
```

and then initialising them again like this:

```
tinymce.init({ selector: 'textarea' });
```

In your example this would be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('click', '.btn.modal', function() {
    var title = $('.modal-title'),
        content = $('.modal-body'),
        footer = $('.modal-footer');

    $.post('units.php', { addnew: 'unit' }, function(r) {
      title.html(r.title);
      content.html(r.content);
      footer.html(r.btns);
      $('textarea').tinymce().re‌​move();
      tinymce.init({ selector: 'textarea' });
      $('#modal').modal('show');
    },'json');
  });

});
```